# file iteration 'NoneType' object not iterable in for loop

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, nonetype

I've looked at the other posts regarding this TypeError but they have not helped me with figuring this out. Where the error is occurring is where I am trying to cycle through the list of returned files from the geotextiles function and then search them for the user's input. But it doesn't seem to be able to step into the 'for I in files:' loop due to a NoneType. What is causing the files list to be none type?

```
# Program to accept user input and search all .txt files for said input

import re, sys, pprint, os


def getTxtFiles():
    # Create a list of all the .txt files to be searched
    files = []
    for i in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')):
        if i.endswith('.txt'):
            files.append(i)

def searchFiles(files):
    ''' Asks the user for input, searchs the txt files passed,
     stores the results into a list'''
    results = []
    searchForRegex = re.compile(input('What would you like to search all the text files for?'))
    for i in files:
        with open(i) as text:
            found = searchForRegex.findall(text)
            results.append(found)


txtFiles = getTxtFiles()
print(searchFiles(txtFiles))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "searchAll.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(searchFiles(txtFiles))
  File "searchAll.py", line 19, in searchFiles
    for i in files:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `return files` on your `getTxtFiles` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getTextFiles() doesn't return anything.

Functions don't have declared return types in python, so without an explicit return statement your function returns None.

```
def getTxtFiles():
# Create a list of all the .txt files to be searched
    files = []
    for i in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')):
        if i.endswith('.txt'):
            files.append(i)
    return files <------this is missing in your code-----
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Illustration, issue reproduction.

>>> import re, sys, pprint, os
>>>
>>>
>>> def getTxtFiles():
...     # Create a list of all the .txt files to be searched
...     files = []
...     for i in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')):
...         if i.endswith('.txt'):
...             files.append(i)
...
>>> files = getTxtFiles()
>>> print(files)
None
>>>
>>> for i in files:
...   print 'something'
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Fix is to return files from getTxtFiles().

```
def getTxtFiles():
    # Create a list of all the .txt files to be searched
    files = []
    for i in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')):
        if i.endswith('.txt'):
            files.append(i)
    return getTxtFiles()
```